# setup log4j in eclipse to work with quartz job

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, quartz-scheduler

This is my `log4j.properties` file in `WEB-INF/classes` directory:

```
#SET LEVEL of ROOT-LOGGER, you will like to have Debug in local, but in prod you may just want WARN and ABOVE. This setting is done here!
log4j.rootLogger=all, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number. (basically, format of log)
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

# THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL HAVE ALL THE LOG WRITTEN
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/Users/miranda_zhang/Documents/workspace/cloud_demo_3/log/speedtest.log

# Maximum size of log file, usually we keep 10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file, usually we keep 10
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

in the java class I have something like:

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class collectSpeedtestDataJob implements Job {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(collectSpeedtestDataJob.class);

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }

    }
}
```

but nothing get logged in the file `/Users/miranda_zhang/Documents/workspace/cloud_demo_3/log/speedtest.log`

Following are the messages shown in **Console**:

```
Apr 7, 2013 4:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Apr 7, 2013 4:24:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:demo_3' did not find a matching property.
Apr 7, 2013 4:24:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 7, 2013 4:24:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 7, 2013 4:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1993 ms
Apr 7, 2013 4:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 7, 2013 4:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.19
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  rest.handler
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:03 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.12 02/15/2012 04:51 PM'
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 7, 2013 4:25:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 19119 ms
```

I have added `-Dlog4j.debug=true` as a VM Argument in Eclipse.

I have tried the following to debug:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    logger.info("Log - collectSpeedtestDataJob");
    System.out.println("info logged");

    try {

        DB.executeUpdate(speedtest());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

}
```

In the **Console**, I can see this being printed, but nothing in the log file:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
info logged
```

Comment: Are you seeing logs in the console? Is this class getting initialized? You are printing the log in the catch block here. Does the code reach there. Alternatively, you can try printing it in the try block itself, and see if it appears in the console. Your settings seem to be fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have added the following code to solve the problem:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("absolute/path/to/your/WebContent/WEB-INF/log4j.properties");
```

But still would like to know if there is a way to detect the file automatically. Or getting the path of the file automatically.

```
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = loader.getResource("/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j.properties");
```

only gives me `null`